# jQM: Only some transitions work after dynamic HTML injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

When I inject large amounts of HTML into the DOM with data pulled with Ajax, I for-loop through the data and inject something based on each entry. Each injected element is some `<a>` with `data-transition='slide'`.

**The Problem:** Currently out of the 21 entries I inject, only the transitions for the first 6 work. I've tried several things, i.e. injecting everything at once, injecting everything in little pieces, calling `.trigger('create')`, or `.page()` on the containing `div` after, and calling it on each injection, and even adding a setTimeout(500) after each element in the for-loop. NOTE: for the elements that don't work, there is no transition at all, not even the default one.

**Simplified Sample Code:**
This is called in a callback function for a `$().ajaxSubmit` request,

```
function populateFeed(data) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#feed").append("<a href='#nextpage' onclick='someFunction()' data-" + 
       "transition='slide'><div>Some content</div></a>");
  }
}
```

The actual code has a little bit more logic than this, but this is the core. So why is this only working for the first 6, but feels like jQM transitions break for the latter ones? How do I fix this?

**Update:**
A similar effect has been reproduced at http://jsfiddle.net/Uk5d4/6/. The links near the bottom (i.e. link 999) has no transitions.

Comment: Do you use slide on all pages or only on those links?

Comment: Only on those links, I have tried to set the default to slide also, the broken links still show no transition.

Comment: Try calling `$('data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate')`. Edit: if you force refreshing the page, do they work?

Comment: `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate')` returns error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js:3`, and I believe force refresh of a page is `.trigger('create')`. I have tried `$("#feed").trigger('create')`, `$("#idOfPage").trigger('create')`, as well as the same for ('pagecreate'), placed after the for-loop. Nothing changes. Edit: `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('create')` also does nothing.

Comment: Weird...the on,y solution I can think of now, is using `$.mobile.changePage()`. It's even easier than appending attribute to each anchor. All you need to do is the following little code `$('#feed').on('click', 'a', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); var page = $(this).attr('href'); $.mobile.changePage(page, { transition: 'slide' }); });` if div #feed is also dynamically added, `$(document).on('click', '#feed a', function (e)`.

Comment: I removed all of the data-transition tags, and made sure that everything was correct, where the first 6 would have the default fade and the others still broken somehow. And then I added your snippet of code after the for-loop, the first 6 now once again slide, the rest still broken.

Comment: Are you using `.ready` somewhere? Can you reproduce this issue on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Uk5d4/3/

Comment: You can reproduce the issue if you set the length to 1000. The bottom links will have the broken transition. I can imagine that this has something to do with the loading time and that it only takes 6 to break it for me because there is a lot of CSS and also images to load.

Comment: Working with 1000 links. There should be something else breaking the links.

Comment: try link 999, the transition into doesnt work but the reverse transition does. http://jsfiddle.net/Uk5d4/6/

Comment: Yup, you're right. I tried even appending new pages dynamically, the same is happening.

Comment: have you managed to fix it? Edit: I just noticed something, when you scroll down, the problem appears.

Comment: I have not managed to fix it, but the problem is more than that error it throws. My project does not throw this error but still has the same behavior. Other things I've tried that hasn't worked: injecting a new page and creating that new page, nesting all the `<a>` in a listview.

Comment: I guess it's a scroll issue. for creating pages dynamically, check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/YJuJ5/

Answer (score 0):

try loading the jqm js after u have completed with your dynamic creation of html. 
JQM transforms the html already created when the first time it is loaded. so if you are creating anything afterwards, it is nt able to transform them, thus we need to call this js again.